# `Exists`and `IN` give two different results in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, exists

> The `in` Query

```
SELECT * FROM commodity 
WHERE id IN (SELECT cid FROM specifications s WHERE s.id<600);
```

> The `EXISTS` Query

```
SELECT * FROM commodity  
WHERE exists(SELECT c.* 
              FROM specifications s,commodity c 
              WHERE  s.id < 600 and c.id = s.cid );
```

Why am I getting two separate results using the above two queries. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: They are very different. IN checks to see if a specific value is in a query, while exists just checks to see if a record exists. Use the one that is appropriate to your purpose. The 2nd query will not run as fast as the first.

Comment: A fairer question might be "Why would you imagine them to be the same?" !?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `JOIN` operation in the subquery of the `EXISTS` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM commodity c 
WHERE exists(SELECT c.* 
              FROM specifications s
              WHERE  s.id < 600 and c.id = s.cid );
```

The two queries are now equivalent provided that `id` is a not `NULL` field.

Comment: `SELECT c.*` ??

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't think it makes any difference to use either `SELECT 1` or `SELECT c.*` or `SELECT c.id` in the suquery of the `EXIST` operator.

Comment: one more question, when I execute: show profiles   to see query id why  some SQ L  disappear  and other query id changes their query id?

Comment: sql> SELECT * FROM commodity WHERE id IN (SELECT c_id FROM specifications s WHERE s.id<600)
[2017-07-14 15:39:20] 39 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 28ms (execution: 8ms, fetching: 20ms)
---------------
sql> SELECT * FROM commodity WHERE exists(SELECT 1 FROM specifications s,commodity c WHERE  s.id < 600 and c.id = s.c_id )
[2017-07-14 15:40:13] 595 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 47ms (execution: 12ms, fetching: 35ms)

Comment: I thought the second one will be quicker than the one, is the first one have to scan the whole table? the second one used the index. why the second slower than the first one ?

Comment: Can you post the `EXPLAIN` output of both queries?

Answer (score 0):

You are NOT linking the outer Commodity table in the inner query. It should be like this.

```
SELECT * FROM commodity c 
WHERE exists(SELECT s.* 
               FROM specifications s
              WHERE  s.id < 600 and c.id = s.cid );
```